# Find the limit of $a_n=\left(\frac{3n^4+n^2+n(-1)^n}{2n^4+i^n+n^2}\right)_n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Find the limit of $a_n=\left(\frac{3n^4+n^2+n(-1)^n}{2n^4+i^n+n^2}\right)_n$

I assume that it tends to $1.5$ since I did some tests. For example $a_{10000}\approx 1.5$.

I also know that $n^4$ increases the fastest and the quotient of their coefficients is equal to $1.5$. But I haven't proved that yet, is there an easier method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the fact that\begin{align}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{3n^4+n^2+n(-1)^n}{2n^4+i^n+n^2}&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\displaystyle3+\frac1{n^2}+\frac{(-1)^n}{n^3}}{\displaystyle2+\frac{i^n}{n^4}+\frac1{n^2}}\\&=\frac{\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}3+\frac1{n^2}+\frac{(-1)^n}{n^3}}{\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}2+\frac{i^n}{n^4}+\frac1{n^2}}.\end{align}

Comment: understood. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Value of this limit depends on the value of $i$

If $i\gt1$ then limit is equal to $0$ or else, it is $1.5$

Hope this helps!

Comment: Since $i$ is a fixed number, that answer makes no sense.

Comment: Ya, but the range in which $i$ lies matters as it change the value of limit. OP didn't specified the limit of $i$, that's why I wrote that!

Comment: Don't you really see that $i$, here, is $\sqrt{-1}$?

Comment: Oh, my Bad! I thought $i$ is just a constant, not complex no i. If that is the case, then it is of no use.